# Combine two table in a new one

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

I have two tables in a Postgres , table 1 with hosts, ips and severity, and table 2 with geo localization of each networks. I need to create a table 3 with all data of the table 1 and comparing the host (table 1) with network from table 2 to add on table 1 de column site, how can I do this.

```
TABLE 1     
HOST        |     IP            | SEVERITY
HOST - 1    | 172.2.36.2        |   7
HOST - 2    | 172.2.34.35       |   7
HOST - 3    | 172.2.36.9        |   8
HOST - 4    | 172.2.34.77       |   6
HOST - 5    | 172.2.36.2        |   5
HOST - 6    | 172.2.36.99       |   3
HOST - 7    | 172.2.34.55       |   4


TABLE 2 
NETWORK     | SITE
172.2.36.   | SITE A
172.2.34.   | SITE B


TABLE 3     (NEW)   
HOST        | IP            | SEVERITY  |   SITE
HOST - 1    | 172.2.36.2    |   7       |  SITE A
HOST - 2    | 172.2.34.35   |   7       |  SITE B
HOST - 3    | 172.2.36.9    |   8       |  SITE A
HOST - 4    | 172.2.34.77   |   6       |  SITE B
```

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owrHj.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dzh.png)

[Table Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A9zL.png)

Thanks

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to formatted text.

Comment: Your expected results do not include HOST - 5, 6 and 7. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot ... I need only severity >=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join of `Table1` to `Table2`:

```
select t1.*, t2.site
from Table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.ip like concat(t2.network, '%')
where t1.severity >= 6
```